# Browser Memory consumption / leak issues

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, memory-management, memory-leaks

I need help in understanding this Testing process.
Our Quality Assurance (QA) team is using Performance Monitor (from Microsoft) to test browser memory consumption & leak.

### Steps QA do:

1. Open web browser and login to our webapp.
2. Note down the initial virtual bytes from tool (shown in screenshot)
3. Perform some operation(lets say search) for a couple of times.
4. Note down the virtual bytes from tool.
5. Calculate the difference between last & first virtual bytes allocated. (After converting virtual bytes to MB)
6. Divide this difference by number of total number of clicks performed by user.
7. Note down the remainder.

Now, this remainder should be less than 1. (this number is decided by them)
If its greater than 1, they say our webapp has memory leaks.

For Firefox & chrome, this remainder is less than 1 for us. But for IE 10 & 11 (32 & 64 bit both) remainder is more than 1.

### Questions:

1. Is this some standard practice they are following?
2. How correct is their analysis process?
3. How can I convince them, if their analysis is not so right?
4. How should I go about fixing this problem?

P.S I'm not able to get more information from our QA.

P.S We use angular js for Client.

[image: Snapshot from tool]

Comment: Interesting question, and a common issue. QA all have their own techniques and there's usually little you can do to change their process. Their process likely exists for very good reason. Though I've not personally experienced this process it seems perfectly valid. Some are stricter than others it's just how things go. The only thing you haven't mentioned is if you've carried out any of your own memory leak testing, Chrome is quite good at this by record heaps and analysing usage. If you need some direction on how to do this let me know and I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note down the initial virtual bytes from tool (shown in screenshot)

Virtual bytes are nearly meaningless on 64bit because large chunks of address space can be reserved ahead of time without actually backing them with RAM or swap. Of course the amount is somewhat correlated to actual memory use, but it's just that "somewhat".

> Calculate the difference between last & first virtual bytes allocated. (After converting virtual bytes to MB)

This calculation can be meaningless for a different reason. Browsers use complex memory management systems (custom allocators and garbage collectors) which may not immediately release memory back to the operating system after they have used it. Which means that for some amount of time their memory usage may only appear to grow, not shrink, even when you close tabs.

> How should I go about fixing this problem?

Use the built-in memory tracking tools of the browsers. E.g. `about:memory` in firefox.